# Elastic search aggregations: "aggs" query- "field" vs "script"- which is faster?

Tags: elasticsearch

aggregation query to get count based on "cityId" and "cityName":

```
 "aggs": {
        "CityIdCount": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "cityId",
            "size": 0
          }
        },
        "CityNameCount": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "cityName",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
```

aggregation query to get count based on "cityId" and "cityName" using script:

```
"aggs": {
    "CityIdCount": {
      "terms": {
        "script": doc["cityId"] + doc["cityName"],
        "size": 0
      }
    }
```

How these query get processed inside elastic? Which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Both are scary because of `"size": 0`, which indicates that it wants to retrieve *every* available value (up to `INT_MAX`). That will eventually cause a memory explosion and that's not good for anyone.

For starters, native options are always going to be faster than scripts without question. It's better to look over [the documentation for what the `terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) does because there a lot of little edge cases (e.g., `shard_size`), but also because both examples are `terms` aggregations so they do the same thing.

The difference is that when the aggregation goes to check each document for the script, it needs to do more work: it needs to execute a Groovy script that will concatenate two values, then return the *single*, concatenated value as the term for said document. If the document happened to have an array for `cityId` or `cityName`, then the non-scripted version would actually end up recognizing all values while the script would only recognize a single one (and probably not work as intended).

As a side note, you want the script to be

```
"script" : "doc['cityId'].value + doc['cityName'].value"
```

rather than the one that you're showing as an example, which is completely invalid.

What you probably want is:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "CityIdCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cityId",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "CityNameForId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "cityName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again, without the terrifying `"size" : 0`. This will give the `cityName` for every `cityId`.

Comment: You are correct- it needs to be "script" : "doc['cityId'].value + doc['cityName'].value". I missed that part. So you are suggesting that using groovy script would be expensive here, right? I was thinking that in other approach- by searching with "field":"cityId" first and then by "field":"cityName", isn't it double work. I guess elastic search would internally count for ids first and then for name. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: In both cases, it needs to seek to the doc values touched by the aggregation. In the case of your first example, you have two separate, technically unrelated aggregations that run against all documents each individually grabbing the doc values as it goes. In the second case, your have a single aggregation with a script [extra overhead] that grabs both values in the same go of it while concatenating the two [minor overhead]. In my last example, it only does the second aggregation _for_ the first aggregation, so it groups the values together, which is probably what you want. Don't over-optimize.

Comment: ok. I completely missed the subtle difference b/w approach you suggested vs my 1st approach. I have document of cars with each having (cityId,cityName). I just want my output to be (cityId, cityName, count). Here count is number of times (cityId, cityName) is repeated. We have one cityId mapped to one cityName and vice-versa. I guess your approach is the most optimum one. I would try this and let you know. Can you please confirm if it would be right thing. I hope you got the exact situation now.

Comment: The query you suggested is not working. Its giving me error- "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;

Comment: Ah woops, I forgot to add the inner "aggs" level of nesting. I made the entire request a bit more realistic. And with the 1:1 situation, I think this is superior.

Comment: I can't test right now. I hope you got the scenario and this would work for my scenario? Anyways i will let you know tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you can also tell, how can i avoid using "size": 0?

Comment: That's realistically a different problem. Within the terms aggregation, size 0 means to grab _all_ possible values (up to `INT_MAX`). In matters of scale, that's simply not reasonable. In smaller use cases where "all" translates into 10000 or so, it's not as severe (e.g., if there's only 10000 unique `cityId`'s, then have at it). The problem really comes down to need. Do you really need all 10K city IDs in one response? Why do you even need them _all_ in the first place? Are you really just looking for the "top" ones? Stuff like that.